# How to get the type of an annotation using the JDT AST?

Tags: java, annotations, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have an `IAnnotation` instance, how can I get the fully qualified type name of the annotation, if `IAnnotation#getElementName()` returns the simple name?

```
    IAnnotation ruleAnnotation = field.getAnnotation("Rule");
    String fullQualifiedName = ???
    if (fullQualifiedName.equals("org.junit.Rule")){
        ...
    }
```

I found this answer, but this is a different use case:
    [How to determine if a class has an annotation using JDT, considering the type hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230505/how-to-determine-if-a-class-has-an-annotation-using-jdt-considering-the-type-hi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you speak about `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IField` and `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IAnnotation` (part of the "Java Model" - not AST), you should do s.t. along these lines:

```
IAnnotation ruleAnnotation = field.getAnnotation("Rule");
IType declaringType = field.getDeclaringType();
String elementName = ruleAnnotation.getElementName();
String[][] fullyQualifiedName = declaringType.resolveType(elementName);
```

Please consult the javadoc of `IType.resolveType(String)` for extracting the qualified name from the 2-dim array.